# MySQL too many joins and rows - execution time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run a query but there are just too many joins hence the slow execution time. I'm looking at other alternatives such as letting PHP process it instead of mysql. Still wracking my brain on how many queries/connections i have to run. Any suggestions?

**5 Tables and their Rows**
2Variations increases by 5000 rows per year
di increases by maybe 100,000 per year
docs increases by 50,000 per year
type and hashtag are constants of about 20 each

**VARIABLES**
Now here the thing with my query
$groups = group by type OR group by hashtag OR both
$query_where = REGEXP to only find a particular type and/or hashtag from a list of array (selected by user), its like find_in_set

```
$query_where .=  "AND CONCAT(',', `type.product_type`, ',') REGEXP ',($types_arr),' ";
```

The query below runs at about **38 seconds**
*This is only if $groups = type.product_type only
and
$query_where = ""*

```
        SELECT 
type.product_type as type, hashtag.variation_hashtag as hashtag,
di.warehouse, sum(di.qty)as qty, sum(di.price) as price, sum(di.sold_price) as sold_price, sum(di.cogs) as cogs, avg(di.price) as ave_price, avg(di.sold_price) as ave_sold_price, 
YEAR(docs.created_on) as year, MONTH(docs.created_on) as month
        FROM  2Variations v
            LEFT JOIN docs_inventory as di on di.product_id = v.product_id
            LEFT JOIN docs on docs.id = di.doc_id
            LEFT JOIN variations_type_link as type on v.id = type.id
            LEFT JOIN variations_hashtag_link as hashtag on v.id = hashtag.id
        WHERE
            di.deleted = 0 and
            type.deleted = 0 and
            (hashtag.deleted = 0 or hashtag.deleted is null) and 
            di.warehouse between 1 and 2
            ".$query_where."
        GROUP BY
            YEAR(docs.created_on), MONTH(docs.created_on), ".$groups;
```

**EXPLAIN**

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+--+
| id | select_type |  table  |  type  |   possible_keys    |    key     | key_len |          ref          | rows |                    Extra                     |  |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+--+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | type    | ALL    | PRIMARY,deleted    | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                  | 4730 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,product_id | PRIMARY    | 4       | database.type.id      |    1 | Using where                                  |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | hashtag | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY    | 4       | database.v.id         |    1 | Using where                                  |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | di      | ref    | product_id         | product_id | 4       | database.v.product_id |  218 | Using where                                  |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | docs    | eq_ref | PRIMARY            | PRIMARY    | 4       | database.di.doc_id    |    1 | NULL                                         |  |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+--------------------+------------+---------+-----------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+--+
```

**THE CREATE TABLE**

```
Create Table
2Variations CREATE TABLE `2Variations` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `auto_reorder` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `qty_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `color` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `supplier_code` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `barcode` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `upca` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `no_pic` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `restock` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `hashtag` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
 `php_wholesale` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `php_retail` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `weight` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `notes` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
 `company_notes` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
 `mgnt_notes` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
 `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `retired` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `created_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
 `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
 `last_update` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
 KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5083 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci



docs    CREATE TABLE `docs` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id in table customers',
     `registered_id` int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `doc_type` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0: none, 1:PO, 2:DR, 3:INV, 4: RS',
     `doc_no` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `doc_date` date NOT NULL,
     `duedate` date DEFAULT NULL,
     `confirm_date` date NOT NULL,
     `paid` date NOT NULL,
     `paid_amount` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `sf` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `rsf` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `vat` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `vatinex` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1 = in, 2 = ex',
     `merc_total` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
     `payment` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
     `commission` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
     `discount` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
     `voucher_amount` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
     `bundle_discount_amount` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
     `shipped` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     `ext_courier` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
     `ext_courier_tracking` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
     `ext_orderid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
     `ext_total_weight` decimal(11,4) NOT NULL,
     `notes` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
     `company_notes` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
     `mgnt_notes` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
     `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id in users',
     `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
     `updated_by` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id in users',
     `last_update` datetime NOT NULL,
     `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `deleted_reason` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `doc_no` (`doc_no`),
     KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`),
     KEY `ext_courier_tracking` (`ext_courier_tracking`,`ext_orderid`),
     KEY `ext_orderid` (`ext_orderid`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=77904 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci



docs_inventory  CREATE TABLE `docs_inventory` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `doc_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id in table doc',
     `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id in table products',
     `color` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `qty` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `warehouse` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
     `price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
     `sold_price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
     `cogs` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
     `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `doc_id` (`doc_id`),
     KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=395438 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci



products_type_link  CREATE TABLE `products_type_link` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `product_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
     `product_type` int(20) NOT NULL,
     `created_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
     `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
     `updated_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
     `last_update` datetime NOT NULL,
     `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `product_type` (`product_type`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4088 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci



variations_hashtag_link CREATE TABLE `variations_hashtag_link` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `variation_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
     `variation_hashtag` int(20) NOT NULL,
     `created_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
     `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
     `updated_by` int(20) NOT NULL,
     `last_update` datetime NOT NULL,
     `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `variation_hashtag` (`variation_hashtag`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3703 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**UPDATED INDEX to include Deleted got slower to 45secs**

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+--+
| id | select_type |  table  |  type  |        possible_keys         |    key     | key_len |          ref           |  rows  |                    Extra                     |  |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+--+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | di      | ref    | product_id,warehouse,deleted | deleted    |       4 | const                  | 169837 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | docs    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                      | PRIMARY    |       4 | database.di.doc_id     |      1 | NULL                                         |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v       | ref    | PRIMARY,product_id           | product_id |       4 | database.di.product_id |      2 | Using index                                  |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | hashtag | eq_ref | PRIMARY                      | PRIMARY    |       4 | database.v.id          |      1 | Using where                                  |  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | type    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,deleted,deleted_2    | PRIMARY    |       4 | database.v.id          |      1 | Using where                                  |  |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+------------------------------+------------+---------+------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+--+
```

Comment: It seems like a complex query, and your performance could be suffering for multiple reasons, like indexing and the REGEXP string searching. String searching is kinda slow.

You should run an EXPLAIN query using your favorite tool and see what can be optimized

Comment: Also include `SHOW CREATE TABLE 2Variations` and for all others too in your question so the indexes can be evaluated.

Comment: `type.product_type IN {list}` can be faster in some MySQL versions. Is that acceptable? What mysql version (`SELECT VERSION()`)?

Comment: Updated my question to show the index. Right now its not even utilizing the regexp as ive set query_where to "".

Comment: Lots of joins isn't necessarily the main factor in query speed

Answer (score 0):

another alternative way for massive queries is creating a temp table and fill it using SQL jobs.
for example, every 10 minutes execute the big query , insert it into the temp table Then just write the query for the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer; too long for a comment...

First off, in order to help, we'd really need to see the complete query, and personally, I find it easier to read when formatted, e.g. as follows:

```
SELECT t.product_type type
     , h.variation_hashtag hashtag
     , di.warehouse
     , SUM(di.qty) qty
     , SUM(di.price) price
     , SUM(di.sold_price) sold_price
     , SUM(di.cogs) cogs
     , AVG(di.price) ave_price
     , AVG(di.sold_price) ave_sold_price
     , YEAR(d.created_on) year
     , MONTH(d.created_on) month
  FROM 2Variations v 
  JOIN docs_inventory di 
    ON di.product_id = v.product_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN docs d
    ON d.id = di.doc_id 
  JOIN variations_type_link t 
    ON t.id = v.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN variations_hashtag_link h
    ON h.id = v.id
 WHERE di.deleted = 0 
   AND t.deleted = 0 
   AND (h.deleted = 0 or h.deleted IS NULL)
   AND di.warehouse BETWEEN 1 AND 2
".$query_where."
 GROUP 
    BY YEAR(d.created_on)
     , MONTH(d.created_on)
     , ".$groups;
```

Note that I've replaced a couple of the OUTER JOINs with INNER JOINs because they weren't really OUTER JOINs to begin with. Also, it's really weird to join two tables on a column called 'id'. By convention, an 'id' column represents something unique to that table, so a user table might have a column called 'id', and an account table might have a column called 'user_id'.

Comment: is that the di.doc_id = docs.id?

Docs is the ORDER which contains the dates. Di are the details of the docs.
v, type and hashtag contains details of Di

Comment: No; it's wherever 'x.id = y.id'

Answer (score -1):

for your SQL, the following talbes are working

- 2Variations => rows : A
- variations_type_link => rows : B
- variations_hashtag_link => rows : C
- docs_inventory => rows : D
- docs => rows : E

so if your original query will run, working rows for join and where will be A*B*C*D*E
after A*B*C*D*E operations, group by will work.

improve SQL run speed. you have to reduce operaion count and set index key.

do not worry we can improve execution time :)

**#1 at first, you have to check that the following field is set by indexing**

- 2Variations => id, product_id
- variations_type_link => id, deleted
- variations_hashtag_link => id, deleted
- docs_inventory => product_id, doc_id, deleted, warehouse
- docs => id

**#2 avoid to use between operation**
    di.warehouse between 1 and 2 : this is wrong for fast speed
    ( warehouse >= 1 AND warehouse <= 2 ) : good for fast speed

**#3 try to reduce join operations by using sub select**
    if you show my finial query, you can have a sense

I am sure that following query will work very quickly :)

```
SELECT dtbl.type, dtbl.hashtag, dtbl.warehouse, sum(dtbl.qty)as qty, sum(dtbl.price) as price, sum(dtbl.sold_price) as sold_price, sum(dtbl.cogs) as cogs, avg(dtbl.price) as ave_price, avg(dtbl.sold_price) as ave_sold_price, 
    YEAR(docs.created_on) as year, MONTH(docs.created_on) as month FROM
(
    SELECT btbl.*, di.* FROM
    (
        SELECT atbl.product_id, atbl.type, hashtag.variation_hashtag as hashtag FROM
        (
            SELECT v.id, v.product_id, type.product_type as type FROM
                2Variations as v
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT id, product_type FROM variations_type_link
                WHERE deleted = 0
            ) as type
            ON v.id = type.id
        ) as atbl
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT id, variation_hashtag FROM variations_hashtag_link
            WHERE deleted = 0 OR deleted IS NULL {$query_where}
        ) as hashtag
        ON atbl.id = hashtag.id
    ) as btbl
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT ctbl.*, YEAR(docs.created_on) as year, MONTH(docs.created_on) as month FROM
        (
            SELECT product_id, qty, warehouse, price, sold_price, cogs, price, sold_price FROM docs_inventory
            WHERE deleted = 0 AND ( warehouse >= 1 AND warehouse <= 2 )
        ) as ctbl
        LEFT JOIN
            docs
        ON ctbl.doc_id = docs.id
    ) as di
    ON btbl.product_id = di.product_id
) as dtbl
GROUP BY YEAR(dtbl.created_on), MONTH(dtbl.created_on), {$groups}
```

Comment: Do you have any evidence for any of the assertions made above. Please remove those which you cannot substantiate